# Easiest way to align text in a table cell

Tags: html, center, alignment

I know very little html and pretty much no css. I would like to know the easiest way for me to change my left aligned text to center aligned within the cells. Someone on stackoverflow helped me to figure out how to center a table on my wordpress page with the following code:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <table style="margin: 0px auto;" border="0">
        <table border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>ddd</td>
                    <td>ddd</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

I now need to figure out how to center the text within the cells. I have tried using align="center" beside the td. This showed the text centered in the wordpress admin area, but on the actual webpage, the text was still left aligned. Another guy recommended I put something in my header code and link it to the something. Again, I know very little about this and would appreciate the easiest solution. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td style="text-align:center"></td>
```

If you want every cell centered, the easiest solution for you is to add the above to every cell.

you dont need the div above or the style in the table tag, and only one table tag :)

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center">centered text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh thank you thank you. I knew it was something small that I was missing. (this is not my forte) I was just going to stick with left align; now, my site will look so much better. Many thanks.

Comment: what's the url (web address)? :)

Comment: It's an errand running business. I would give it but I want to keep it as secret as possible right now.     :
0

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS (CSS has to be added within `<style>` tags):

```
<style>
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Also.. remove one of the `<table>` tags:

```
<table style="margin:0px auto;" border="0">
<table border="0">
```

should be

```
<table style="margin:0px auto;" border="0">
```

Comment: @JackStevens Tip bookmark these sites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here are two simple ways:

```
<td align="left">foo</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">foo</td>
```

**EDIT**

As others have mentioned, you also need to remove the nested `<table>` tags.

Comment: Thank you as well James. I have so much to learn. You guys who speak this "language" are geniuses in my opinion!

Comment: align="left" is not future proof use style=""

Comment: @Christian: I agree, but I thought it might be a bit easier to grasp for a newbee.